# Pass arguments when using the File protocol

Tags: protocols, command-line-arguments, file-uri

I found this question being asked on several places on the internet (including the [File protocol MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28VS.85%29.aspx)) but no clear answer.

So, if I am calling my application like this:
***file://c:\myapp.exe***
is there any way to pass it some command line arguments, like ***/nospashscreen=true***

Things I've tried:

***file://c:\myapp.exe?/nospashscreen=true*** - launches the app, but with no command line arguments :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Windows?  If so, there is no way to pass a parameter using the "file://" syntax, as it is an [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(VS.85).aspx) that does not accept parameters.

However, if you really need it, you can craft your own pluggable protocol that accepts parameters.

Here's an example:

[An Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol Handler for data: URLs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DataProtocol.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass on the arguments using # (hash) symbol.

Comment: Could you give an example on how the syntax should be? If I call file://c:\myapp.exe#param1 I will get a "file not found" exception

Comment: I don't know about running `.exe` files, but this works for passing GET parameters to files loaded with the `file:///` protocol. IE10 automatically repeats the variables, e.g. : `file:///c:/index.html#var=val` becomes `file:///c:/index.html?var=val#var=val`. It's not necessary though. You can just call `file:///c:/index.html?var=val`.

Comment: This is accepted on an application-specific basis, I believe. See https://superuser.com/a/969616/904401