# passing parameters to file uri

Tags: windows, uri, parameter-passing

im trying to mail localy the software with the input parameters so software will be opened up with the contex data.

is there a way to mail the link to open the software ?
tried the uri, which allows to open the software with 
file://

however the uri does not seem to handle parameters. do you know how?

Is it possible to pass parameters to

```
File://C:\folder\a.exe value1 value2
```

?

if this is not the syntax, what is the currect syntax?

assuming this is a local system.

Comment: I think it must work in that way. do you encounter some problems? I think you run it using a command line

Comment: can you be a little more specific about context.  Usually on the windows command line you don't specify `File://`, the only time I've seen that is with an internet browser.  Usually you just specify `C:\folder\a.exe value1 value2`.  I think windows has special behaviour for handling URIs, but it looks like you just want to run the program (it doesn’t need to be a URI).

Answer (score 0):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141333/9731176, this does not appear to be possible in most contexts:

> I am assuming you are using Windows? If so, there is no way to pass a parameter using the "file://" syntax, as it is an Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol that does not accept parameters.